# Why should the call to AppSignatureHelper class be removed from the app after we get the hash string?

Tags: android, sms-retriever-api

The following document :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify

states that for computing App's hash string we can use AppSignatureHelper class from the SMS retriever sample app. 
It adds , "However, if you use the helper class, be sure to remove it from your app after you get the hash string. Do not use hash strings dynamically computed on the client in your verification messages."

My doubt is,
Will there be any security issues if we retain it in production ?

Comment: ask the opposite question instead. What reason do you have to keep it?

Comment: Message isn't focusing on the deletion of that class but asking not to compute hash dynamically.

Comment: @TimCastelijns we need to keep the helper class to compute app hash key.

Comment: what do you need to compute hash keys for in production?

Comment: @TimCastelijns please refer to the doc link provided

Comment: I was asking rhetorical questions. You don't need to compute hash keys in production, and you don't have any reason to keep the class.

Comment: Then how will i get the app hash key to be appended at the end of the SMS (directed to the app)?

Comment: I also wonder why Google would recommend that? What risk is there? Its certainly much easier for apps to send the server they request the SMS code from their signature to sign the message. Especially when one has alpha, beta, dev and prod versions all with distinct unique playstore signed packages.